# Create a crosstable of the variable labels across two and more dataframes

Tags: r

I would like to compare the variable labels across multiple dataframes. I have downloaded the SPSS datasets of the Global Entrepreneurship Monitor using haven package. I would like to create a crosstable listing all unique variable labels across multiple dataframes horizontally and all dataframe vertically. I would then like to fill each table with an x if the variable label is contained in a data frame. MRE of two datasets can be found below the code.

I have started with the following code that seems to get the unique variable labels per dataframe:

```
library(labelled)
libary(tidyverse)
# Get an overview of the same variables across all data frames
# combine data frames into a list
df_list <- list(GEM2001, GEM2002)

# extract unique variable names across all data frames
var_label <- Reduce(union, lapply(df_list, var_label))

# custom function to extract variable labels from each data frame and compare to unique names
check_vars <- function(df) {
  vars_in_df <- var_label(df)
  sapply(var_label, function(x) ifelse(x %in% vars_in_df, "x", ""))
}

# apply custom function to each data frame in the list
df_var_mat <- lapply(df_list, check_vars)

# create cross table
cross_table <- table(df_var_mat, dnn = c("DataFrame", "Variable"), useNA = "ifany")
```

Minimum reproducible example of the data:

```
# First dataset: 
structure(list(setid = structure(c(7700001, 7700002, 7700003, 
7700004, 7700005, 7700006), label = "Harmonization ID", format.spss = "F12.0", display_width = 14L), 
    setid_ne = structure(c(1000000007700001, 1000000007700002, 
    1000000007700003, 1000000007700004, 1000000007700005, 1000000007700006
    ), label = "Alternative ID variable to avoid duplicates across years", format.spss = "F15.0", display_width = 17L), 
    yrsurv = structure(c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001), label = "Year survey was administered", format.spss = "F4.0"), 
    country = structure(c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), label = "Country", format.spss = "F4.0", display_width = 9L, labels = c(`United States` = 1, 
    Russia = 7, Egypt = 20, `South Africa` = 27, Greece = 30, 
    Netherlands = 31, Belgium = 32, France = 33, Spain = 34, 
    Hungary = 36, Italy = 39, Romania = 40, Switzerland = 41, 
    Austria = 43, `United Kingdom` = 44, Denmark = 45, Sweden = 46, 
    Norway = 47, Poland = 48, Germany = 49, Peru = 51, Mexico = 52, 
    Argentina = 54, Brazil = 55, Chile = 56, Colombia = 57, Malaysia = 60, 
    Australia = 61, Indonesia = 62, Philippines = 63, `New Zealand` = 64, 
    Singapore = 65, Thailand = 66, Japan = 81, Korea = 82, Vietnam = 84, 
    China = 86, Turkey = 90, India = 91, Pakistan = 92, Iran = 98, 
    Canada = 101, Morocco = 212, Algeria = 213, Tunisia = 216, 
    Libya = 218, Ghana = 233, Nigeria = 234, Angola = 244, Barbados = 246, 
    Ethiopia = 251, Uganda = 256, Zambia = 260, Namibia = 264, 
    Malawi = 265, Botswana = 267, Portugal = 351, Luxembourg = 352, 
    Ireland = 353, Iceland = 354, Finland = 358, Lithuania = 370, 
    Latvia = 371, Estonia = 372, Serbia = 381, Montenegro = 382, 
    Croatia = 385, Slovenia = 386, `Bosnia and Herzegovina` = 387, 
    Macedonia = 389, `Czech Republic` = 420, Slovakia = 421, 
    Guatemala = 502, `El Salvador` = 503, `Costa Rica` = 506, 
    Panama = 507, Venezuela = 582, Bolivia = 591, Ecuador = 593, 
    Suriname = 597, Uruguay = 598, `* 'Azores'` = 620, Tonga = 676, 
    Vanuatu = 678, Kazakstan = 701, `Shenzhen*` = 755, `Puerto Rico` = 787, 
    `Dominican Republic` = 809, `Hong Kong` = 852, `Trinidad & Tobago` = 868, 
    Jamaica = 876, Bangladesh = 880, Taiwan = 886, Lebanon = 961, 
    Jordan = 962, Syria = 963, `Saudi Arabia` = 966, Yemen = 967, 
    `West Bank & Gaza Strip` = 970, `United Arab Emirates` = 971, 
    Israel = 972), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), weight = structure(c(0.947503767410607, 0.919003654090076, 
    0.924603676356567, 1.01710404415125, 0.716602849315504, 0.83510332049034
    ), label = "Weight provided by data vendor", format.spss = "F8.6", display_width = 10L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), label = "JN725 - IAE - GEM 2009")

# Second dataset
structure(list(setid = structure(c(1121800009, 1121800025, 1121800031, 
1121800035, 1121800036, 1121800039), label = "Harmonization ID", format.spss = "F12.0", display_width = 14L), 
    setid_ne = structure(c(2000001121800009, 2000001121800025, 
    2000001121800031, 2000001121800035, 2000001121800036, 2000001121800039
    ), label = "Alternative ID variable to avoid duplicates across years", format.spss = "F15.0", display_width = 17L), 
    yrsurv = structure(c(2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002), label = "Year survey was administered", format.spss = "F4.0"), 
    country = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "Country", format.spss = "F4.0", display_width = 9L, labels = c(`United States` = 1, 
    Russia = 7, Egypt = 20, `South Africa` = 27, Greece = 30, 
    Netherlands = 31, Belgium = 32, France = 33, Spain = 34, 
    Hungary = 36, Italy = 39, Romania = 40, Switzerland = 41, 
    Austria = 43, `United Kingdom` = 44, Denmark = 45, Sweden = 46, 
    Norway = 47, Poland = 48, Germany = 49, Peru = 51, Mexico = 52, 
    Argentina = 54, Brazil = 55, Chile = 56, Colombia = 57, Malaysia = 60, 
    Australia = 61, Indonesia = 62, Philippines = 63, `New Zealand` = 64, 
    Singapore = 65, Thailand = 66, Japan = 81, Korea = 82, Vietnam = 84, 
    China = 86, Turkey = 90, India = 91, Pakistan = 92, Iran = 98, 
    Canada = 101, Morocco = 212, Algeria = 213, Tunisia = 216, 
    Libya = 218, Ghana = 233, Nigeria = 234, Angola = 244, Barbados = 246, 
    Ethiopia = 251, Uganda = 256, Zambia = 260, Namibia = 264, 
    Malawi = 265, Botswana = 267, Portugal = 351, Luxembourg = 352, 
    Ireland = 353, Iceland = 354, Finland = 358, Lithuania = 370, 
    Latvia = 371, Estonia = 372, Serbia = 381, Montenegro = 382, 
    Croatia = 385, Slovenia = 386, `Bosnia and Herzegovina` = 387, 
    Macedonia = 389, `Czech Republic` = 420, Slovakia = 421, 
    Guatemala = 502, `El Salvador` = 503, `Costa Rica` = 506, 
    Panama = 507, Venezuela = 582, Bolivia = 591, Ecuador = 593, 
    Suriname = 597, Uruguay = 598, `* 'Azores'` = 620, Tonga = 676, 
    Vanuatu = 678, Kazakstan = 701, `Shenzhen*` = 755, `Puerto Rico` = 787, 
    `Dominican Republic` = 809, `Hong Kong` = 852, `Trinidad & Tobago` = 868, 
    Jamaica = 876, Bangladesh = 880, Taiwan = 886, Lebanon = 961, 
    Jordan = 962, Syria = 963, `Saudi Arabia` = 966, Yemen = 967, 
    `West Bank & Gaza Strip` = 970, `United Arab Emirates` = 971, 
    Israel = 972), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), weight = structure(c(0.666652666946661, 1.35532689346212, 
    0.886868262634747, 0.247242055158897, 1.7567198656027, 0.595583088338233
    ), label = "Weight provided by data vendor", format.spss = "F8.6", display_width = 10L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), label = "JN725 - IAE - GEM 2009")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```r
library(haven)
library(labelled)

# for testing, add discordant labels for one variable
var_label(GEM2001$weight) <- "Weight provided by data vendor"
var_label(GEM2002$weight) <- "Weight according to vendor"

df_list <- list(GEM2001 = GEM2001, GEM2002 = GEM2002)

df_labels <- lapply(df_list, \(df) unlist(var_label(df)))
all_labels <- unique(unlist(df_labels))

label_table <- data.frame(label = all_labels)
for (df in names(df_labels)) {
  label_table[[df]] <- ifelse(all_labels %in% df_labels[[df]], "X", "")
}

label_table
```

```r
                                                     label GEM2001 GEM2002
1                                         Harmonization ID       X       X
2 Alternative ID variable to avoid duplicates across years       X       X
3                             Year survey was administered       X       X
4                                                  Country       X       X
5                           Weight provided by data vendor       X        
6                               Weight according to vendor               X
```

**Edit:**

OP asked "Is there an easy way to replace the 'X' in the crosstable with the variable name?" To do so, change the `for` loop as follows:

```r
for (df in names(df_labels)) {
  label_table[[df]] <- ifelse(
    all_labels %in% df_labels[[df]], 
    names(df_labels[[df]])[match(all_labels, df_labels[[df]])], 
    ""
  )
}

label_table
```

```r
                                                     label  GEM2001  GEM2002
1                                         Harmonization ID    setid    setid
2 Alternative ID variable to avoid duplicates across years setid_ne setid_ne
3                             Year survey was administered   yrsurv   yrsurv
4                                                  Country  country  country
5                           Weight provided by data vendor   weight         
6                               Weight according to vendor            weight
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to replace the "X" in the crosstable with the variable name @zephryl?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following aproach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_list = list("df1"=df1, "df2" = df2)

bind_rows(lapply(names(df_list),\(n) {
  tibble(frame=n, labels=unlist(var_label(df_list[[n]])))
})) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = labels, names_from=frame, values_from=frame,values_fn = length)
```

Comment: This also works totally fine, just a minor detail is not as described! I wish I could accept two answers as most helpful!